# Use local file as set_thumbnail on embed in Discord.py

Tags: python, image, discord, discord.py, embed

I want to post an embed with a thumbnail on it, with a local file on my PC.
Whenever I try to run this code, the image is sent outside the embed.

```py
embedVar = discord.Embed(title="title",
                        description="desc.",
                         color=0X19A6FF)
file = discord.File("file_location/file.png", filename="image.png")
embedVar.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://file_location/file.png")
await message.channel.send(file=file, embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 6):

The filename in the `File` constructor and the filename in the `URL` must match. Currently you're passing the whole path, it's supposed to be only the name

```py
embedVar.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://image.png")
```